# Why is my ajax call refreshing the page?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to upload an audio file via AJAX form.

Here is my HTML in the profile-edit template.

```
<form method="post" id="my_upload_form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="my_file_input" accept="audio/*">                                      
  <input type="submit" class="btn-submit btn-sumary" value="upload audio file" name="submit" id="my_audio_submit">                                      
  <div id="my_error_report"></div>                                  
</form>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#my_upload_form').submit(function () {

    var css = 'font:Helvetica; color:red; font-size:1.5em; padding:inherit;';
    var html = '<strong><em> ' + '<p style="' + css + '">' + '*';
    var endHtml = '</p></em></strong>';

    var formData = new FormData();
    var fileArray = jQuery('#my_file_input').prop('files');

    if(fileArray.length > 0) {
        var theTrack = fileArray[0];
        formData.append("music", theTrack);
    } else {
      jQuery('#my_error_report').html( html + 'no track selected' + endHtml );
      return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      type: 'POST',
      // async: false,
      data: {
          action      : 'my_track_upload',
          some_data   : formData
      },
      // dataType: 'text'
      }).success( function( data ) {
          /* You win! */
          alert('ajax was called success');
      }).fail( function( data ) {
          /* You lose, show error */
          alert('ajax was called failure');
    });
    return false;  
});
```

Finally here is my plugin code:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_track_upload', 'my_track_upload');
function my_track_upload()
{
  die('hello');
}
```

Problem (more to come):
Why is the page refreshing? I return false in the jQuery 'submit' event.

************************EDIT********************

I changed my code to the following and it works now, though I'm not sure specifically where the problem was.

...
...
...

```
var theTrack = fileArray[0];
        formData.append('action', 'musistic_track_upload');
        formData.append("music", theTrack);
enter code here
```

...
...
...

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  datatype: "script",
  beforeSend: function() {
    jQuery('#my_error_report').html('');
  }
}).complete(function( data ) {
  jQuery('#my_error_report').html( html + data.responseText + endHtml );
  jQuery('#my_audio_submit').val("Upload Audio File", function() {
    jQuery(this).prop('disabled', false);
  });
});

return false;
```

Comment: Have you checked your javascript `console.log` using developer tools in the case there's javascript errors? Have you tried returning false at the top of your submission listener to narrow down the issue?

Comment: The error is: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
Could it be that the AJAX call wants a string in the some_data parameter?
I've seen many examples using the same method I have above.

Comment: Double check $ is set to jQuery. By default it is not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment jgraup. I open my js file with 'jQuery(document).ready(function($) {', so I don't think that's the error. I also have another function that disables the submit button when it is clicked.

Comment: Ah yes, I've run into this same issue recently. It has nothing to do with WordPress ( so it's off topic here ) but the issue is that you need to append your action to your `formData()` object so that the only thing that gets passed into data is: `data: formData`. No brackets, no name identifier just exactly like that. You can append your action exactly like you're appending `music`. Hopefully that works for you!

Comment: Yes, I tried McGee's way, and additionally added processData: false to my options before it worked.

Comment: However, the ajax response is now returning 0.

Comment: This is an issue with the hook. Try adding [nopriv](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)) and maybe print to [error log](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) before dying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a crucial line in my AJAX query. Without this option, the call fails, and the pages refreshes.

```
processData: false,
```

Comment: I tried everything else, but this DID it immediately. I had a form action and an Ajax call listening for the 'click' event. This was third-party software and when I tried to change to 'submit' nothing would get submitted. Doing processData: false, magically solved everything.

Answer (score 7):

Try using `preventDefault()`, it's a jQuery function for preventing default actions called by the browser.

First you should call an event handler by firing up your submitter. You can do this as follow:

`$('#my_upload_form').submit(function (event) {`

After catching a submit and giving an event with it, you should prevent the default refresh of a browser:

`event.preventDefault();`

Now your code will look as follow:

```
$('#my_upload_form').submit(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var css = 'font:Helvetica; color:red; font-size:1.5em; padding:inherit;';
    var html = '<strong><em> ' + '<p style="' + css + '">' + '*';
    var endHtml = '</p></em></strong>';

    var formData = new FormData();
    var fileArray = jQuery('#my_file_input').prop('files');

    if(fileArray.length > 0) {
        var theTrack = fileArray[0];
        formData.append("music", theTrack);
    } else {
      jQuery('#my_error_report').html( html + 'no track selected' + endHtml );
      return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      type: 'POST',
      // async: false,
      data: {
          action      : 'my_track_upload',
          some_data   : formData
      },
      // dataType: 'text'
      }).success( function( data ) {
          /* You win! */
          alert('ajax was called success');
      }).fail( function( data ) {
          /* You lose, show error */
          alert('ajax was called failure');
    });
});
```

BTW: Always try to place `preventDefault()` on top of the function, it should prevent the default action before anything else is done.

Comment: Good suggestion. I just fiddled with the AJAX call until it worked. To my shame, I still don't fully understand why. 

For those interested in further reading on preventDefault and 'return false' this is a good thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false